# Is babel supposed to throw syntax errors?

Tags: node.js, browserify, babeljs

I have setup a node.js [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) file to use the [babel](https://babeljs.io/) transform allowing me to utilize ES6 features in browser scripts.

When I add an intentional syntax error to the input file I am not seeing any error messages being output by babelify despite having subscribed to the 'error' event as suggested in the [Using Babel with Browserify](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#browserify) guide.

Example of invalid syntax:

```
immmmport $ from 'jquery';
```

Instead of showing an error in the CLI it just silently fails.

Here is how I have configured my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('build', () => {
    browserify(options)
        .transform(babelify)
        .add(sourceFilePath)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(outputFileName))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulpif(!argv.production, sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true })))
        .pipe(gulpif(argv.production, streamify(uglify())))
        .pipe(gulpif(!argv.production, sourcemaps.write('/')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDirName));
})
```

Am I missing any steps here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of this problem was that I needed to add the following line:

```
.on("error", err => { gutil.log("Browserify Error", gutil.colors.red(err.message)) })
```

So that I have this:

```
gulp.task('build', () => {
    browserify(options)
        .transform(babelify)
        .add(sourceFilePath)
        .bundle()
        .on("error", err => { gutil.log("Browserify Error", gutil.colors.red(err.message)) })
        .pipe(source(outputFileName))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulpif(!argv.production, sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true })))
        .pipe(gulpif(argv.production, streamify(uglify())))
        .pipe(gulpif(!argv.production, sourcemaps.write('/')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDirName));
})
```

The following page was useful in diagnosing this issue:

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1044